# Why include $0$ and $1$ in the signature of Presburger arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, theories-of-arithmetic, definability

I recently became interested in some problems concerning decidability of extensions of Presburger arithmetic. However, being a number-theorist rather than a logician, I am confused by some notational questions which are probably very basic.

Presburger arithmetic is the first order theory of the integers with addition. Depending on the context we can work with $(\mathbb{N};+)$ or $(\mathbb{Z};+,<)$ — the two corresponding first order theories are definitionally equivalent(?). However, in the literature I often see $0$ and $1$ also included in the signature. For an concrete example, [A Survival Guide to Presburger Arithmetic](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/christoph.haase/home/publication/haa-18/haa-18.pdf) by C. Haase uses the notation $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{Z},0,1,+,<)$, but the pattern is more general.

My point of confusion is: $0$ and $1$ are easily definable in the language of $(\mathbb{Z},+,<)$. Indeed, $0$ is defined by the property that $x+0 = x$ for all $x$, and $1$ is defined by that $1 > 0$ and there does not exist $x$ with $1 > x > 0$. In this case, what is the rationale behind including $0$ and $1$ in the signature? Am I missing some fundamental point and they are not really redundant? Or is there a reason why one would write first order theories in a redundant way?

Comment: It's the same with PA, which includes 0, 1, and <, but these are all definable from + and *. Nevertheless, it is convenient to have these part of the language, and if one didn't have them one would immediately form the definitional expansion. Since it is harmless (conservative etc), what is the objection?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins There's no objection, there's just confusion. Usually, in my experience, definitions include the minimal amount of information that is required, so it came as a surprise that this is not the case here.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462298/why-include-0-and-1-in-the-signature-of-presburger-arithmetic#comment1199491_462298), I'm not sure it is uniformly common to include the minimum amount of structure necessary in a definition.  For example, groups need only the single operation $(a, b) \mapsto a b^{-1}$ satisfying appropriate axioms, but most definitions instead equip them with two operations and a constant.

Comment: A nice thing about Presburger arithmetic is elimination of quantifiers when you add relations such as "$\exists x (y=x+x+x)$". For this to work, you need to have 0 and 1 in the signature. It's like elimination of quantifiers for the real field R; inequality < is easily definable, but if you want to eliminate quantifiers then you need < in the language. Maybe this is a good motivation for having 0 and 1.

Comment: @Pasten And indeed, every theory admits elimination of quantifiers in the full definitional expansion, where a predicate is introduced for every definable relation (and constants, functions for every definable element and function). So that phenomenon is fully general.

Comment: @Pasten You don't need $0$ for quantifier elimination, only $1$. And if this is the motivation, why are the congruence predicates not in the language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the same in Peano arithmetic, where the standard language is $\{+,\cdot,0,1,<\}$ for the standard model $\langle\mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle$, even though $0$, $1$, and $<$ are definable from $+$ and $\cdot$.

The reason to have the larger language is simply convenience in expressing things, and indeed I believe that if one introduced initially only the restricted language, then the first thing one would do is introduce the expanded language as a definitional expansion.

Precisely because the definitional expansion is conservative over the weaker theory, there is no harm in doing this and much to gain for ease of expressibility. Indeed, the two theories are bi-interpretable, and usually one regards bi-interpretable theories as having the same semantic content. From this perspective, there is no essential mathematical difference between the two approaches.

One might observe that mathematics overflows with definitional expansions. In groups, the identity element $e$ is definable from the group operation, but it is certainly convenient to have it; and the inverse operation $a^{-1}$ is definable, but this also is convenient. Set theory overflows with definable predicates, since the base language officially has only $\in$, but often even the axioms are expressed using defined expressions such as $\cap$, $\cup$, $\emptyset$, $P(x)$, and $\{x\in a\mid \varphi(x,z)\}$.